How to get this stuff off the bottom of my oven?
I have a new oven (Cafe/GE, if that matters) and like to keep it really clean. So much so that I line the bottom with black teflon sheets, which are removable and very easy to clean.
However, I idiotically ran the self cleaning cycle the other day, and forgot to remove the sheets, which turned white and left this residue on the floor of the oven, and it won't come out:

Curiously, when it's wet, as shown in the middle, the white residue does disappear, but when it dries, it comes back. Scouring with an abrasive pad does a better job, but also scratches the metal, which is probably even worse.
This is a brand new oven and I'm really upset about it. What might get this out?

scratches the metal ... scratches the enamel, not the metal

try asking at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions ... they might know about the chemicals that are released by Teflon at high temperature

Pyrolysis of Teflon (PTFE) produces toxic and corrosive waste products, including carbonyl fluoride, carbonyl difluoride, difluorophosgene, hexafluoroethane, hydrogen fluoride, octafluorocyclobutane, octafluoroisobutylene, fluorine monoxide, perfluoroisobutylene and tetrafluoroethylene.
This page gives some information on toxicity. Of particular note, perfluoroisobutylene is internationally recognized as an agent for chemical weapons due to its toxicity; a single exposure to just 0.5 ppm will kill 50% of rats.
The point is, if you do any further cleanup, wear personal protective equipment.
I think you'll find that the enamel coating on the steel interior of your oven has been permanently etched by the fluoride waste products including hydrogen fluoride. If so, it will never be smooth and will attract soil. What appears to be a white coating may actually be etched enamel, which is a form of glass.
If a replacement bottom panel is available from the manufacturer, that's your best bet.
If you paid for the oven with a credit card, check to see if the card carries any kind of coverage for accidental damage. You might be pleasantly surprised.

I was puzzled because burning Teflon is supposed to smell bad and there was no smell at all when this was happening. I can't find the order for this exact product, but I have another, very similar material, and this is described as being made of "Fiberglass Teflon PFOA free". So I'm thinking it wasn't Teflon after all. I'm not sure it changes anything about cleaning, but I'm hoping it means it's less toxic. Do you know anything about that?

@JoshuaFrank No smell: you had good ventilation? Fiberglass Teflon PFOA free is still Teflon and the pyrolysis products are the same. It just has embedded glass fibers for tear resistance. PFOA free means it contains no perfluorooctanoic acid. Some Teflon formulas contain it. PFOA is implicated in human diseases so it's best not to have any in products with possible food contact. Suggest you find your original order so you know if it was Teflon or not. You could also search for an identical appearing / functioning product that is not Teflon, and if you can't find one, it was Teflon.

We used to use aluminum foil/disposable aluminum pans.
